# Transform data returned in Mongo query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Documents in my collection are like following :

```
[
  {"cat": "A", "catDesc": "abc", "subcat": "1", "subcatDesc": "123", "name" : "Tom", "age" : 22},
  {"cat": "A", "catDesc": "abc", "subcat": "1", "subcatDesc": "123", "name" : "Paul", "age" : 19},
  {"cat": "A", "catDesc": "abc", "subcat": "2", "subcatDesc": "456", "name" : "Jack", "age" : 25},
  {"cat": "A", "catDesc": "abc", "subcat": "2", "subcatDesc": "456", "name" : "Liu", "age" : 21},
  {"cat": "A", "catDesc": "abc", "subcat": "3", "subcatDesc": "789", "name" : "Ace", "age" : 18},
  {"cat": "A", "catDesc": "abc", "subcat": "3", "subcatDesc": "789", "name" : "Pan", "age" : 20},
  {"cat": "B", "catDesc": "def", "subcat": "1", "subcatDesc": "123", "name" : "Shawn", "age" : 23},
  {"cat": "B", "catDesc": "def", "subcat": "1", "subcatDesc": "123", "name" : "Dom", "age" : 25},
  {"cat": "B", "catDesc": "def", "subcat": "2", "subcatDesc": "456", "name" : "Paul", "age" : 16},
  {"cat": "B", "catDesc": "def", "subcat": "2", "subcatDesc": "456", "name" : "Ace", "age" : 21}
]
```

Now I want to write a mongo query which would transform the data when returned. Should be something like :

```
[ {"cat" : "A",
   "catDesc" : "abc",
    subcats : 
    [
      {"subcat" : "1",
       "subcatDesc" : "123",
       "Details" : [{"name" : "Paul", "age" : 19}, {"name" : "Tom", "age" : 22}]
      },
      {"subcat" : "2",
       "subcatDesc" : "456",
       "Details" : [{"name" : "Liu", "age" : 21}, {"name" : "Jack", "age" : 25}]
      },
      {"subcat" : "3",
       "subcatDesc" : "789",
       "Details" : [{"name" : "Ace", "age" : 18}, { "name" : "Pan", "age" : 20}]
      }
    ]
  },

  {"cat" : "B",
   "catDesc" : "def",
    subcats : 
    [
      {"subcat" : "1",
       "subcatDesc" : "123",
       "Details" : [{"name" : "Shawn", "age" : 23}, {"name" : "Dom", "age" : 25}]
      },
      {"subcat" : "2",
       "subcatDesc" : "456",
       "Details" : [{"name" : "Paul", "age" : 16}, {"name" : "Ace", "age" : 21}]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The data should be transformed as above and also the `"cat"` should be sorted alphabetically and the `"subcats"` should be sorted by subcat number and the `"details"` should be sorted by age

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite easy to achieve by just [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)ing twice like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $sort: {
            age: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {cat: "$cat", subcat: "$subcat"},
            details: {$addToSet: {name: "$name", age: "$age"}},
            subcatDesc: {$first: "$subcatDesc"},
            catDesc: {$first: "$catDesc"}
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.cat",
            catDesc: {$first: "$catDesc"},
            subcats: {
                $push: {
                    subcat: "$_id.subcat",
                    subcatDesc: "$subcatDesc",
                    Details: "$details"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            subcats: 1,
            catDec: 1,
            cat: "$_id"
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            cat: 1,
            catDec: 1
        }
    },
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Helped a lot. Just one thing. The `cat` and `subcat` is not sorted as I wanted. Only the `Details` is sorted by `age`.

Comment: You can just add a `$sort` stage at the end. ill edit it in.